# printing the return of a function. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function

Have trouble with this small bit of code. Getting the error in the title. Can someone possible fix it for me or tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks

```
import tkinter as Tk

from tkinter import filedialog 

def chooseDcmFile():

  root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select dcm File", filetypes=("dcm files", "*.dcm"))

  file = root.filename

  return(file)


from pydicom import dcmread

def dcmread():

   if file == none:

    file = chooseDcmFile()

   dcmFullData=dcmread(file)

   return (dcmFullData)   

print dcmread()
```

Comment: Why do you import `dcmread` and then immediately redefine it as `def dcmread()`? What is `file` in your new function?

Comment: I could have defined it as something else but kept my function the same as the module I am importing to make it easier for me to read

Comment: That doesn't help since your `def dcmread()` renders the import redundant. Your new function is now recursive!

Comment: Sorry I miss wrote the code...module being imported is dcmread. The function I am defining is dcmreader (note er at the end). My point was that I was keeping the two similar to make it easy for myself but I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant this:

```
import tkinter as Tk

from tkinter import filedialog 

def chooseDcmFile():
  root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select dcm File", filetypes=("dcm files", "*.dcm"))
  return root.filename


from pydicom import dcmread

def dcmreader():
    file = chooseDcmFile()
    dcmFullData = dcmread(file)
    return dcmFullData

print(dcmreader())
```